# React how to change checkbox from true to false if checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6

As the title says I want to change value of checkbox from true to false or false to true when clicked. I'm not sure how to change it. I'm presuming "setState" but how exactly I am not sure

```
toggleCheckboxChange(e) {

let isState = e.target.value;


if(isState != false) {
   isTrue = isState
}
if(isState == false) {
  isTrue = isState;
}
  //change state of checkbox
}
  render() {

weatherInfo = <WeatherInfo
      nameOfCity={nameOfCity}
      weatherDescription={weatherDescription}
      windSpeed={windSpeed}
      temperature={temperature}
      maxTemperature={maxTemperature}
      minTemperature={minTemperature}
      myPokemon={myPokemon}
      change={this.toggleCheckboxChange.bind(this)}
  />;


const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
        <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
        <li>{props.windSpeed} m/s </li>
        <li>{props.temperature} °C</li>
        <li>{props.maxTemperature}°C</li>
        <li>{props.minTemperature}°C</li>

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={false}
            onChange={(e)=>props.change(e)}
        />
    </ul>
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are toggling the checked status of checkbox is incorrect because if you make use of two `if` block both will be executed and hence even when the first one executes the second one will see the updated result and change the calue again.

Also you are not retuning the updated value or setting it in the state. Do That as shown in the below example. Also in your `WeatherInfo` component you have set the checked status to `false` and hence it will remain false all the time. You should be receiving the prop and setting the checked status to this prop.

Also make sure you set the initial state to be either `true` or `false`

```
toggleCheckboxChange(e) {

let isState = e.target.value;

if(isState == false) {
  isTrue = true;
}
else {
   isTrue=false;
}
  this.setState({checkedState: isTrue})
}
  render() {

weatherInfo = <WeatherInfo
      nameOfCity={nameOfCity}
      weatherDescription={weatherDescription}
      windSpeed={windSpeed}
      temperature={temperature}
      maxTemperature={maxTemperature}
      minTemperature={minTemperature}
      myPokemon={myPokemon}
      checkedState={this.props.checkedState}
      change={this.toggleCheckboxChange.bind(this)}
  />;


const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
        <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
        <li>{props.windSpeed} m/s </li>
        <li>{props.temperature} °C</li>
        <li>{props.maxTemperature}°C</li>
        <li>{props.minTemperature}°C</li>

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={props.checkedState}
            onChange={(e)=>props.change(e)}
        />
    </ul>
</div>
);
```